# Any idea where this chrome bumper is from.

Tags: bumper

This old bumper was found wrapped and tucked away in a corner of the attic of the garage. I am curious if anyone has an idea where it comes from. I have no idea how old it is. It is 65 inches across.
[image]

Comment: Telling us in which country you live will help.

Comment: I’m in Canada. A bit of research based on the Vauxhall comment led to Opel. This led to 1967 and 1968 Camero’s. It seems a great fit for those.

Comment: Not Camero, they don't wrap the body like the one in your picture

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the leads. The Vauxhall comment led me to Opel then GM and then the Camaro. It is bumper for a 1967 Camaro. The wrapping of the bumper changed in 69. This one will fit the 67 or 68 Camaro.

The Vauxhall bumper has a distinct pointed centre whereas this bumper comes to a point but is a straight line from each end.

Answer (score 0):

That's from the 1958 Borgward Isabella Princess Edition.

Or not.

You might try selling it on eBay or similar with a lot of pictures.  Somebody who wants it will pipe right up...

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess would be that it's from a Vauxhall Viva HC.

[image: Vauxhall Viva HC]

Purely on the basis of the little "Vee" in the centre.

[image: Viva front bumper]

Here is a photograph of one removed from the car from a recent eBay listing.

This car was also sold under the name Vauxhall Magnum